# How can I make javascript trigger an event on BlackBerry when a <select> option is selected

Tags: javascript, html, blackberry

I am writing a simple website to be displayed on the BlackBerry browser. (Using the 9700 model as baseline)

I have a simple list of options on the page, like so:

```
<select id="choices">
  <option value="abc" onchange="jsfunction()" onclick="jsfunction()">ABC</option>
  ...
</select>
```

I want to execute a JS function when I select one of the options (so that I dont have to make the user click a button to perform an action - this is a BB browser). However, none of the events (onchange, onclick) displayed above seem to trigger when I try to select the option.

I have verified that JavaScript works in the browser, its just not firing on those events.

Thanks,
Lukasz

Comment: onChange goes in SELECT tag '<select onChange="yourFunction()">'

Comment: @Jose: Oh yea, that totally solves my problem. Derp :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use `onChange`, as [***`Jose Adrian`***](https://stackoverflow.com/users/875777/jose-adrian) (*above*) said.